# Decomposition of symmetric block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, block-matrices

I came across [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88728/factorizing-a-block-symmetric-matrix) and got really interested about it. There, the OP asks whether is possible to decompose a $2n \times 2n$ block matrix:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
X & I \\
I & Y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
into $MDM^{T}$, where:
$$D =  \begin{pmatrix}
0 & I \\
I & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $I$ is the identity matrix. The matrices $X$ and $Y$ where assumed to be *noninvertible*, but $X$ could be assumed to be positive-semidefinite and $Y$ negative semi-definite. I'd like to ask a slightly different question. Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ *are invertible*, but not positive-definite nor negative-definite. Does such a decomposition $MDM^{T}$ exists? In addition, is it possible to find such a decomposition where $M$ itself is invertible?

Comment: you do want $X$ and $Y$ to be symmetric, don't you?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I do. Didn't mention it. My bad.

Comment: Let $n = 2$ and $X = Y = \mathrm{diag}(-1,1)$, then both $X$ and $Y$ are invertible, but the matrix $[[X, I]; [I, Y]]$ is not, and so there does not exist a decomposition with invertible $M$.  More generally, the determinant of your matrix is equal to $\det(XY - I)$, and the determinant of $MDM^T$ is non-positive. So if the product $XY$ is too positive a decomposition is also not available.

Comment: Note that in your linked question, the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have opposite signs avoids such obstructions by design.